# Convert dataframe column to dataframe header

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame (df) like this:

```
sem|course|count
sem1|A|1
sem1|B|2
sem1|C|1
sem2|A|2
sem2|B|2
sem2|C|2
sem3|C|2
sem4|A|2
```

From the above data frame,I want output as a dataframe like this:

```
  sem1|sem2|sem3|sem4
A  1|2|0|2
B  2|2|0|0
C  1|2|2|0
```

I have tried the following code:

```
df.groupby(["sem","course"]).apply(list)
```

I haven't got the expected output.Could anyone help?

Comment: df.pivot(index='course', columns='sem', values='count').fillna(0)

Comment: When I do df.columns,I want sem1,sem2,sem3,sem4 as column names which I couldn't achieve with this

Comment: This should work fine. What did you get?

Comment: @thushv89 It displays the following output `Index(['sem1', 'sem2', 'sem3', 'sem4'], dtype='object', name='semester')` I actually need this for the columns and index as subjects.

Comment: @thushv89 I refer to courses by subjects in the above comment